# PHP/MySQL log in system -

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm pretty new to both PHP and MySQL and I'm struggling to get my login system to function properly. The registration works fine, but when I run the login it doesn't recognise there is anything within the table matching the entered data. Below is the code I believe to be the problem area.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

function load($page = 'login.php')
{
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].
dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$url = rtrim($url,'/\/');
$url.= '/'.$page;

header("location:$url");
exit();
} 
function validate($dbc,$email ='',$pwd='')
{
$errors = array();
if (empty($email))
    { $errors[] = 'Enter your email address.'; }
else
    {  $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($email));}
if (empty($pwd))
    { $errors[] = 'Enter your password.';}
else
    { $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($pwd)); }
if (empty($errors))
{
    $q = "SELECT adultID, FirstName, Surname "
            . "FROM adult_information "
            . "WHERE Email = '$e' AND Password = SHA1('$p')";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1)
    { $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return array( true, $row);}
    else
    {$errors[]='Email address and password not found.';}
}
return array(false,$errors);
}
```

Comment: Step through the code and debug. You expect a valid login to follow a path through the code.. dump variables and conditions to find out what path it's actually taking.

Comment: try to print query and see how it looks like.

Comment: This is copy/paste job. Debug this code I found http://answer.techwikihow.com/913804/undefined-function-error-php-cant-why.html

Comment: @OllieJones well maybe he is not working in a bank or working with classified information. If this is his own project, risk is not that big.

Comment: Everyone has to learn somewhere, Ollie. I propose that we avoid totally derailing this thread with continued insults and assumptions and deal with the matter at hand. user3360702, when you echo the contents of `$q`, does the query contain the values you expect? Does it produce the expected results when executed manually against the database?

Comment: @OllieJones will Adobe and Sony Gaming hire PHP noob to work for them? No way!! If your job require handling with any kind of important data, they will check your knowledge. While you learn something, they start working usually with localhost or unknown webhost. I doubt he would not learn about SQL injection by the time his project will reach higher audience.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you'll get what you're looking for if you change

```
$q = "SELECT adultID, FirstName, Surname "
        . "FROM adult_information "
        . "WHERE Email = '$e' AND Password = SHA1('$p')";
```

to

```
$p = SHA1($p);

$q = "SELECT adultID, FirstName, Surname "
        . "FROM adult_information "
        . "WHERE Email = '$e' AND Password = '$p'";
```

Whenever a PHP-to-MySQL query isn't performing as expected, my first step is to get a look at the SQL I'm actually passing to the database. In this case, it would be by inserting a line like `echo '<p>$q</p>';` immediately after assigning the value of $q.

Sometimes it immediately becomes obvious that I've got a malformed query just by looking at it. If it doesn't, I copy the SQL code that appears and run it as a query within the database manager, to see what errors it throws and/or examine the resulting data.